# Как я могу реализовать оценку статьи на сайте

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

У меня есть многостраничный сайт, и в нем много статей. Как я могу при помощи php и mysql (можно и другие методы, главное, чтобы работало) сделать оценку статьи с условием, что с одного ай-пи можно голосовать только один раз? И это при том, что рейтинг при загрузке страницы, разумеется, будет генерироваться динамически? Frontend я уже написал, теперь проблема с back-ом

Comment: https://phppot.com/php/php-star-rating-system-with-javascript/

Comment: у всех  пользователей белые IP чтобы только раз с адреса голосовать?

Comment: Да не, просто человек думает что у каждого юзера уникальный IP.

Comment: @u_mulder Не, ну я знаю, что не у каждого юзера свой ip, а у каждого компа. А что такое белый ip?

Comment: Это в твоей сети локальной у каждого компа свой IP. А за пределы твоей локальной сети эти адреса могут и не распространяться. И все 20 компов твоей локальной сети будут стучаться в гугл с одного IP, выданного провайдером.

Comment: За одним IP могут скрываться тысячи РАЗНЫХ пользователей. Точно так-же один пользователь может скрываться по тысячам IP.

Comment: @NoSkill Хм, я раньше думал, что ip присваивается устройству. Пойду изучать тему